# How to export an animation into unity (sound baked to an f-curve)?

Tags: animation, export, constraints, unity, drivers

I made an animation, using bones and converted sound into an f-curve, like in the first part of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAes-ITNaGA. How can I export this animation into Unity now?

As I understand this animation depends on "constrains" and “drivers” inside Blender, is there an acceptable way to export this animation into Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try FBX (it bakes animation, so it *should* work, provided you are not doing too exotic things). Collada (DAE) is the other format that supports animation, but not sure it’s natively supported by Unity.